# Cant completely change sector 0

Tags: mfrc522

I need to rewrite sector 0 completely (all 16 bytes). I'm using the "Change UID" example from “MFRC522” library for this, changing the NEW_UID in it to the one I need. I also change the length to 16 in MIFARE_SetUid. I get the error "New UID buffer empty, size 0, or size > 15 given". Accordingly, I managed to rewrite only the first 15 bytes. How can I overwrite all 16 bytes of sector 0? Thanks!